# Firefox flickers upon document update

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have an iframe like this:

```
<iframe id="htmlRender">
</iframe>
```

And I have a JS snippet to update the iframe's content:

```
function renderHtml(htmlString) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('htmlRender');
    var doc;
    if (iframe.contentDocument) {
        doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    }
    else if (iframe.contentWindow) {
        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    }
    else {
        doc = iframe.document;
    }

    doc.body.innerHTML = '';
    doc.open();
    doc.writeln(htmlString);
    doc.close();
}
```

When I call `renderHtml`, the content updates correctly. However, I see a flicker in Firefox, which causes a bad UX. I am not seeing other browsers having the same issue.

How can I fix this flicker issue in Firefox? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do the open, writeLn, close stuff. Just do the innerHTML thing.

Like this:

```
function renderHtml(htmlString) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('htmlRender');
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument || 
        iframe.contentWindow.document ||
      iframe.document;

    doc.body.innerHTML = htmlString;
}

renderHtml('<strong>hello</strong');
```

Created this jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/abmkntfq/